# How to check if every odd index in a string has the same letter?

Tags: java

I'm working on this program where I need to verify if every odd index in a String has the letter "X". For example if my String is: AXFXTX then I should get a message: "GOOD", if not I should get a message: "BAD". Can anyone tell me what I'm missing please. Thank you in advanced.

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    System.out.println("Random number = " + randomNum);
    System.out.print("Enter a word of " + randomNum + " characters:");
    String myString = scan.nextLine();

    while(myString.length() != randomNum){
        System.out.print("Enter a word of " + randomNum + " characters:");
        myString = scan.nextLine();
    }

    char[] c  = myString.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < c.length ; i++){
        if(c[i] == 'X'){
            System.out.println("GOOD!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("BAD");
        }
    }       
 }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0 ; i < c.length ; i++){` loops over both even and odd characters. You need to find a way to make it skip the ones you are not interested in.

Comment: @Thilo I know that, but I'm not sure how to skip the ones I dont need

Comment: You are checking every character in your for loop. You only need to check every second (i+=2) starting with 1 and not 0. If your character then does not equal 'X' you can exit the loop and print out 'BAD'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply evaluate odd indices only:

```
char[] c  = myString.toCharArray();
boolean good = true;

for(int i = 3 ; i < c.length ; i+=2){
    if(c[i] != c[i-2]){
        good = false;
        break;
    }
}     

if(good) System.out.println("GOOD");
else System.out.println("BAD");
```

Comment: Aren't you testing *even* indices here?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch well, depends on your perspective.. usually people refer to the 1st, 3rd, 5th... as being odd positions. Since 1st is index 0, 0 is "odd"

Comment: OP's example included `AXFXTX` and `X` which is at index `1`, `3` and `5`. C'est la vie.

Comment: I think `c[1]` should be checked at first. When the input string is something like `A0F0T0`, the program will also give a `GOOD` return

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question, then it's important to note that the first odd index is `1`. So you can start at `3` and check if that, and every subsequent odd number (`index += 2`), is the same as the first. Something like,

```
boolean sameLetter = true;
for (int index = 3; index < c.length && sameLetter; index += 2) {
    sameLetter = (c[1] == c[index]);
}
System.out.println(sameLetter ? "GOOD!" : "BAD");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
booelan allGood = true;
for(int i = 2 ; i < c.length ; i = i + 2){
    if(c[i] != c[0]){
        allGood = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not compare to `c[0` every time?

Comment: @AntonH indeed, could do that instead.

Comment: you don't need to check if the String is at least 3 chars long, your for loop already handles that

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use a regular expression here

`str.matches(".(\\w)(.\\1)+")`    //true is GOOD

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you need a boolean variable here to track if it's consistent across all characters. Second, you need to improve your loop

```
boolean testSucceed = true;

for(int i = 1 ; i < c.length ; i += 2){
  if (c[i] != 'X') testSucceed = false;
  break;
}
if(testSucceed){
  System.out.println("GOOD!");
} else{
  System.out.println("BAD");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the for loop to :
    for(int i = 0 ; i < c.length ; i+=2)
so that it goes over alternate characters.

Comment: and then what?  Still print something for every other character?

Comment: Set a flag & keep checking if those chars are same. If any of those chars are found to be different, just break the loop & print "BAD".

Answer (score -2):

//If NOT divisible by 2- Check only ODD number
Edited: You are suppossed to use modulus % and not division %. My bad
    for(int i = 0 ; i < c.length ; i++){
    if(c[i]%2 != 0){ 
            if(c[i] == 'X'){
                System.out.println("GOOD!");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("BAD");
            }
    }
        }